# How To Make Search Service Application as default

Tags: search

After installing CU update on SP 2016 our SSA not functioning 100%, I have created the new SSA and I am wondering how I can make the new SSA the default one.

Regards

Comment: Are the old and the new SSAs crawling the same contents? In that case you need to delete the old SSA that's not working

Answer (score 0):

Go to web application page from CA - by CA - > select a web application - > go to the general setting from the ribbon - > Click on service connection - > one pop up dialog will be opened with all service application - > **default** will be selected at the top drop down changed to **custom** then select one by one service checkbbox and do not select your old **ssa** select your new **ssa**

Repeat this for each web application.

Run the **full crawl** for all content source.

Note :

Before changing from **default** to **custom**  selection take screenshot of that page, so that you will remember what are the services were selected before the changing.

Difference between **default** and **custom**?

Both will display all service application connections, the difference is -  in **default** we can not select or un select the sa, this will be set by default by the SharePoint where as in custom we can select or un select whichever we want.

For example, you have created all service application in the application server, then you have created a web application - in this case all service application will automatically be attached to that web application, hence it is **default**

On the other hand, you already have created a web application, then you have created a new service application for example in this case search service application - now this newly created service application will not be attached to the any of the web application, and if go to the **default** page (service connection selection) - this will be disabled.  So, in order to enable and connect to web application we need to switch to the **custom** mode.

Comment: Thanks Habibur, what is the different between default and custom?

Comment: Explained in the answer.. please see the difference between default and custom section.

Comment: thanks that was great, just one more question, does the SharePoint Search Host Controller and SharePoint Server Search 16, services needs to be running on both App and WFE server? In my environment I have one APP and one WFE server?

Comment: Running in App server would be sufficient